# Stop a scheduled EJB task in Java EE

Tags: java, containers, ejb-3.0, java-ee-5

I have below scheduled bean which runs discovery method every two minutes.

```
@Stateless(name="MySchedulerBean)
public class MySchedulerBean    
     @Schedule(persistent=false, minute="*/2", hour="*", timezone="GMT"
     public void discover(){
          //run discovery every 2 minute
     } 
}
```

The problem with above approach is that it runs forever. 
Is there any way to stop the method to kick once my discovery is done? Can I conditionally run/stop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches: you could just set a boolean on your bean and have `discover()` check that boolean for whether it ought to run. This will still lead to `discover()` being invoked every two minutes though, only to do nothing. But this will allow you to add a `resumeDiscovery()` method to pick up at a later date.

```
@Stateless(name="MySchedulerBean)
public class MySchedulerBean
     private boolean cancelTimer = false;

     public void stopDiscovery() {
        this.cancelTimer = true;
     }

     @Schedule(persistent=false, minute="*/2", hour="*", timezone="GMT"
     public void discover() {
          if (cancelTimer) {
               return;
          }
          //run discovery
     } 
}
```

Alternatively, you can cancel the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Timer.html) that is handling the job. This is a more permanent solution; you won't be able to restart this scheduled EJB... at least, not easily. That would look like this:

```
@Stateless(name="MySchedulerBean)
public class MySchedulerBean
     private boolean cancelTimer = false;

     public void stopDiscovery() {
        this.cancelTimer = true;
     }

     @Schedule(persistent=false, minute="*/2", hour="*", timezone="GMT"
     public void discover(Timer timer) {
          if (cancelTimer) {
               timer.cancel();
               return;
          }
          //run discovery
     } 
}
```

So now, if you decide to stop discovery, the next time discovery tries to run, the timer on this bean will be cancelled for good.